# Struts2 + Sitemesh + Freemarker doesn't work

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker, sitemesh, web-applications

I've tried every example i could find and I can't get struts2 + sitemesh + freemarker to work on a simple jsp.

I have a very simple web.xml, a single action that just goes to index.jsp, and a simple .ftl decorator that just adds some text to the result.

When I hit `index.action`, the page "seems" to be decorated, but I get the literal `${body}` instead of the actual contents.

Here's my setup:

### web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <description>struts2 test</description>
    <display-name>struts 2 test</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.sitemesh.FreeMarkerPageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.action</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

### struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

### sitemesh.xml

```
<sitemesh>
    <property name="decorators-file" value="/WEB-INF/decorators.xml" />
    <excludes file="${decorators-file}" />

    <page-parsers>
        <parser default="true" class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.DefaultPageParser"/>
        <parser content-type="text/html" class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser"/>
    </page-parsers>

    <decorator-mappers>

        <mapper class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.mapper.ConfigDecoratorMapper">
            <param name="config" value="${decorators-file}" />
        </mapper>
    </decorator-mappers>
</sitemesh>
```

### decorators.xml

```
<decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
    <decorator name="main" page="main.ftl">
          <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

### main.ftl

```
<html>
<head>
<title>${title}</title>
${head}
</head>
<body>
I'm Fancy!<br>
    ${body}<br />
</body>
</html>
```

### index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my title</title>
    </head>
<body>
my body
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/sitemesh-plugin.html for working docs.  You probably need to add:

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>sitemesh-freemarker</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to your `web.xml`.

And rename index.jsp to index.ftl.  Incidentally if you're going to go with sitemesh + freemarker I usually prefer the convention of `*.dec` for the decorators and `*.ftl` for the freemarker templates.